# Using MathType on macOS High Sierra results in poor print quality

Tags: mac, high-sierra, ms-office, printing

I am a MathType (6.7) user on a Mac using MS Word (14.7.2) in Office 2011.

I recently upgraded macOS to High Sierra 10.13.4, causing an unresolved problem with MathType. Namely, when an equation is edited or a new equation is created everything looks fine on the screen, but when I print that equation I get a very low quality result that is unacceptable for publication. However, previously created equations continue to print fine.

I tried upgrading MathType from 6.7e to latest 6.7h, but this had no impact on the problem.

Does anyone have any ideas on the cause and solution to this problem?

Also, is there any update past Nov 2017 on a new version of MathType for Mac Office 2016?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Just to clarify, are you using MS Office 2011 or MS Office 2016? Your first and last sentences appear to contradict each other.

Comment: [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298917/office-2016-does-not-work-with-mathtype-migration-of-word-documents-with-mathty) from Sep. '17 here at AskDifferent may hold some clues. FAQ #17 at [DSSI](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/MathType_Mac/faqs.htm) has some bad news.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but there is no contradiction in my post.   As stated, I am currently using MS Office 2011, the most recent Office version that works with MathType for Mac.   At the same time, there is reportedly a new version of MathType for Mac being developed that will work with MS Office 2016.   The last update on that effort is discussed in a post on this site dated Nov 2017.   I was asking if there is any further update.

Comment: We would recommend that you test our latest MathType 7 (compatible with Mac and Office 2016). You can download a trial version from https://store.wiris.com/en/products/downloads/mathtype. 

Additionally, it would help us if you could provide us a file created with 6.7 where we can reproduce the issue. Please send it to support@wiris.com.